# How to point a double-pointer header to a linked list?

Tags: c

I am writing a program that takes strings from lines of a file, and passes them into a linked list of char arrays/C-style strings.

Here is the struct/typedef I am using:

```
struct linked_list {
    char *string;
    struct linked_list *next;
    };
typedef struct linked_list Node;
```

Now, the function where I am processing the file is the following snippet:

```
void function(char *filename, Node **header) {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp != NULL) {
        int line_count = 0;
        Node *curr = NULL;
        char* line = NULL;
        size_t len = 0;
        ssize_t read;
        while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
            printf("File got: %s\n", line);
            curr = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(*curr);
            curr->name = malloc(line);
            strcpy(curr->name, line);
            printf("Curr added: %s\n", curr->name);
            if (line_count == 0) {
                *header = curr;
                printf("Header assigned curr\n");
            curr = curr->next;
            line_count++;
        }
        header = &curr;
    }
```

The prints confirm that I am successfully assigning the variables. Next, the function to print is as follows:

```
void print(Node *header) {
    while (header != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", header->name);
        header = header->next;
    }
}
```

Which obviously doesn't work because the header doesn't properly point to the list.

How would I go about fixing this? I have tried some things like trying to point the header to the linked list "curr" before adding any values, but that didn't seem to work.

I am new to C, so some syntax may be rough/inefficient (especially the malloc() functions, but I will get to that later.

Here is the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Node* header = NULL;
    function(argv[i], &header);
    print(header);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what's `status`?

Comment: `malloc(<magicNumber>)`, such as `malloc(120)` as you have, is very poor practice. You're `malloc`ing a `Node`, so reserve that size. Something like `curr = malloc(sizeof(Node))`, or even better, `curr = malloc(sizeof(*curr))`. In the latter, even if the type of `curr` changes, you don't need to update the argument to `malloc`. In this case it "works" because 120 is far larger than `sizeof(Node)`, but there would be lots of trouble if `120 < sizeof(Node)`

Comment: ah, my bad you dont need to worry about that. it's an exit status variable that doesn't serve much purpose to this exact function . meant to edit it out

Comment: Thanks @yano. I'll fix that. I was aware it was poor practice, was a temp placeholder while I fixed some other things

Comment: Or clearer: `curr = malloc(sizeof *curr);` if you need memory for whatever it is that `curr` is supposed to be pointing at.

Comment: Your node malloc should not be 120 but sizeof(Node). Your name malloc should be the length of the line. first set header to nil, then in the loop just check if header is nil and if so, set it to curr. this will make it point to the first node.

Comment: `curr = curr->next;` This simultaneously creates a memory leak and sets `curr` to some indeterminate value.

Comment: @johnelemans tried that out with `if (header != NULL) {*header = curr}`, and it seems to be an improvement, but void print() now prints just the final string of the file

Comment: @yano good to know, would I need a temp variable to progress the linked list?

Comment: What's `current`? Understand that for any `header = ` in this function, those changes will _not_ be seen outside of the function. Since you passed `header` as a double pointer, I'm guessing you need to do something like `*header = `,, please post a [mre], there are several unknowns in the code presented.

Comment: sorry again, should have been `curr` instead of `current`.

Comment: IMO, you're trying to do too much in this function. Any linked list should have functions like `insertNode(..)`, `deleteNode(..)`, you have a `print` function, that's good. It looks like you're making an attempt to create your linked list in `function` (use a more descriptive name too, btw), but unfortunately not really meeting that goal. I would read a line of text from the file, and pass that to `insertNode`, along with the list head. That function would handle creating and initializing a new node, handling the corner case of first node in the list, etc.

Comment: That sounds like a good plan. Thanks for the help, I'll try that method, it sounds like it would make more sense.

Comment: Before you write any code, draw out your linked list on paper, where boxes represent nodes and arrows represent the `next` pointer. Go thru the process of understanding what needs to happen when the first node is created, when one is appended to the end, or inserted in the middle. Understand what happens when one is deleted, at the end, in the middle, in the beginning. There are several videos/tutorials online that teach these points, but that's beyond the scope of SO.

Comment: You may draw some ideas from [Singly Linked List of Strings With Sorted Insertion](https://pastebin.com/PechfyQa) You can simply remove the in-order insertion in `add_node()` to improve efficiency. You can create a list-wrapper holding both the `head` and `tail` node addresses for `O(1)` insertion-at-end time as shown in [Singly Linked List of Integers (example)](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A)